# Browser is loading assets on server from absolute path instead of relative

Tags: html, image

### Situation

Recently I started a photo gallery on my server — https://mailo.svetel.cz/photos.

This gallery is generated by gem (third-party plugin). All the photo assets are located in /photos. In HTML the image assets are referenced via relative path

[image: Screenshot of non-functioning HTML]

The strange part is, browser (Safari and Firefox) is loading it as if the path is absolute.

Pretty logically server responds with 404, because there is asset https://mailo.svetel.cz/photos/po_tydnu_venku/thumbs/DSC2433.jpg, but the browser is asking for https://mailo.svetel.cz/po_tydnu_venku/thumbs/DSC2433.jpg .

[image: Screenshot of 404]

Before uploading, I did test the page in same browsers and the same code works locally.

### Questions

1. Why does browser think I am giving him absolute path?
2. Do I need to configure something special for relative addresses when using HTTPS?
3. Do I need to configure some header in nginx to use relative addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root path for https://mailo.svetel.cz/photos is https://mailo.svetel.cz/

To make the browser see /photos as a folder, you need to add the directory separator at the end: https://mailo.svetel.cz/photos/

Comment: Maybe I'll embarrass myself again, but it seems to me there is still something strange happening. When I click on the gallery locally, it goes to `po_tydnu_venku/`, but on server it goes to `po_tydnu_venku`. Any idea why?

Comment: Ah, ok it doesn't. The local server redirects to `po_tydnu_venku/` automatically